# BigQuery - scheduled query report error automatically

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I found that the scheduled queries in `bigquery` didn't have the functions that giving notifications if the dependency table runs error.

For example, the creation of `table A` is based on `table B` and I need to `bigquery` notify me that `table A` has problems today if `table B` runs the error today.
What else tools or software can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [dbt](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/introduction) - this tool can manage the order of table builds and data lineage. It has support for BigQuery through supported Data Warehouse [profiles](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/bigquery-profile). It also includes a framework for testing the underlying SQL code, so you can be sure your table build won't fail in prod due to any bugs in your code. Plus many other features...

Alternatively, You can assign a Google Cloud [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) topic to a scheduled query. So a GCP native solution may involve chaining [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) using Pub/Sub and/or using the new [Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/overview) service, which helps to *link series of serverless tasks together in an order you define*. So in this scenario you could check the existing BigQuery job status before executing the next job (table build).